# CKR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL = 0x00000150

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I want to PInvoke C_Encrypt() "pkcs#11" from a .dll :

```
[DllImport("cryptoki.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern UInt32 C_Encrypt(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession,IntPtr pData,CK_ULONG ulDataLen,out IntPtr pEncryptedData,out CK_ULONG pulEncryptedData);

/*
.... Main
in which I initialize the encryption parametrs with C_EncyptInit
*/ 
CK_BYTE[] text = new CK_BYTE[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x08, 0x09 };

System.UInt32 t, tt = (System.UInt32)text.Length;
IntPtr pdata = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(text.Length);
Marshal.Copy(text, 0, pdata, text.Length);

IntPtr chif = IntPtr.Zero;
tt = (System.UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(pdata);
rv = C_Encrypt(h, pdata, tt, out chif, out t);
```

help please

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of different problems here.

1. Your P/Invoke signature is wrong. The final two parameters are not `out` parameters. The `C_Encrypt` function will write the encrypted data to those parameters, but you need to allocate and pass them yourself.
2. You need to allocate data for `chif`, and then pass the size that you allocated for `chif` as the final param `t`. This is the root cause of the error that you're seeing.
3. Nit: Your variable names are confusing, and you seem to have mixed up `tt` and `t` somewhere, since you assign to `tt` twice.

Comment: Thanks for your Help,, but i make a mistake in my question; with this code I have an other error 0x00000021 CKR_DATA_LEN_RANGE. What do you think about this error; Help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem By my self:

```
  [DllImport("D:/Program Files/Eracom/ProtectToolkit C SDK/bin/sw/cryptoki.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern UInt32 C_Encrypt(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, CK_BYTE[] pData, CK_ULONG ulDataLen, CK_BYTE[] pEncryptedData,ref CK_ULONG pulEncryptedData);
```

enjoy